# Ansible - how to run the same command on multiple shell in one task

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run the ip link command using ansible 
on one box ip command located on /bin/ip and other box /usr/sbin/ip

```
   - name: verify the MAC address
     shell: /usr/sbin/ip link
```

```
   - name: verify the MAC address
     shell: /bin/ip link
```

how any thought to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible scenario that should put you on track:

1. Decide one of the commands is the default. For the example, I'll go with `/usr/sbin/ip`
2. In your inventory (example in single file ini format), add a var for machines that are not using the default command

   ```
   machine_a
   machine_b
   machine_c ip_cmd_path="/bin/ip"
   ```
3. In your playbook, run the default command unless there is an override

   ```
   - name: Demo run default cmd unless override
     hosts: all
     tasks:
       - name: run ip command
         shell: "{{ ip_cmd_path | default('/usr/sbin/ip') }} link"
   ```

You can adapt this to target groups rather than machines. You can also have your default command in a variable if needed. Finding the best option depends on your exact requirements.